# I want to identify the public IP of the execution environment of Terraform and add it to the firewall rule

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, firewall

I would like to identify the public IP of the terraform execution environment and add it to the "source_range of the GCP firewall delivery. Objective to allow access only through this address

I am currently manually editing the values in the terraform.tfvars file

For example:

```yaml
public_ip_address {
default = "xx.xx.xx.xx"
}
```

I would like to automate this process, but I have not found a way that does not use a request for an external system, for example on the platform  `http://ipv4.icanhazip.com`

Is there a way to do these things?

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: So the output of one part of running `terraform apply` should be consumed by the other part of code before applying that?

Comment: No, I want to take the public IP of the machine that is running Terraform and add it to the firewall rule

Comment: And the machine is in GCP or it's a local machine, i.e. a PC/Mac?

Comment: A PC/Mac that provides a GCP environment

Comment: Typically your machine is behind a NAT/Gateway. Your machine does not know its public IP address. Therefore you need to make an external request to obtain the public IP.

Answer (score 0):

As [John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720) mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65506593#comment115816914_65506593) you will need to make an external request if the machine your Terraform client is running on has a private IP address assigned to its NIC.

However, you can make the external request (to eg. https://ifconfig.me) from your `main.tf` by using [curl](https://curl.se/) (or any other command-line utility in your system) through an [external data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source):

**main.tf**:

```
# Fetch the external IP address via an HTTPS service with curl
data "external" "curlip" {
    program = ["sh", "-c", "echo '{ \"extip\": \"'$(curl -s https://ifconfig.me)'\" }'"]
}

# Reference curl's result within your resource
public_ip_address {
    default = data.external.curlip.result["extip"]
    ...
```

You will then probably need to run `terraform init` so it installs the required [hashicorp/external](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external) plugin, and after that it will fetch the external IP address with `curl` every time you run `terraform apply`.